# Launching an app into the last view it was closed while running

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Can someone help with a method of how to launch into a view that an might have quit in or suspended in. E.g.

1. I launch the app.
2. Go Open a couple of views within the a and end up in View 4.
3. Quite the app or go into background mode.

I have read that NSUserDefaults can be used but I am just not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the view in the userdefaults with:

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"view4";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"lastView"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then you can load the last view from the userdefaults when the user starts your app again (e.g. in the *ViewDidLoad* in your startView).

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"lastView"];
```

After that you navigate to the view depending on the savedValue.

Keep in mind that you don't really save a view or something. You just save a short string or value that allows you to know which view you want to load again.

**Update in Swift:**

To save the last view:

```
let valueToSave = "view4"
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setValue(valueToSave, forKey: "lastView")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

And after the restart of the app:

```
if let loadedView = userDefaults.valueForKey("lastView") {
    // load your view
}
else {
    // no last view saved
}
```